# Does a family from the EU get the status of Familia Numerosa in Spain, if they live in Spain but are not Spanish citizens?

Tags: eu-citizens, children, spain, benefits

Is it possible to achieve the status of [Familia Numerosa](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familia_numerosa) in Spain, if you are a family from the EU (but not Spanish) and live in Spain?

And if not: Is it enough, if only one parent is Spanish citizen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [one of the references](http://www.consumer.es/web/es/economia_domestica/familia/2007/09/18/167024.php) in Wikipedia article you're linking to:

Simplest case is that members of the family are Spanish nationals, or EU nationals, or EEA nationals, and they all are Spanish residents.

> Para poder adquirir la consideración de familia numerosa, sus miembros
>   deberán ser españoles o nacionales de un estado miembro de la Unión
>   Europea, o de alguno de los restantes estados que hayan suscrito el
>   Acuerdo sobre el Espacio Económico Europeo, y tener su residencia en
>   territorio español.

Alternatively if some of family members are EU or EEA residents in countries other than Spain, at least one family member must have „economic activity” (as in work or have own business) in Spain.

> Si residen en otro estado miembro de la Unión Europea (UE), o en
>   alguno de los restantes estados que tomen parte en el Acuerdo sobre el
>   Espacio Económico Europeo, al menos uno de los ascendientes debe
>   ejercer una actividad económica, por cuenta propia o ajena, en España.

Yet another alternative is family, which members are not citizens of EU nor EEA. In that case only the family members that have residence in Spain are taken into account.

> Los miembros de la unidad familiar que sean nacionales de otros
>   países, tienen derecho al reconocimiento de la condición de familia
>   numerosa en igualdad de condiciones que los españoles, siempre que
>   residan en España todos los miembros que dan derecho a los beneficios
>   que refiere la ley de Protección a la Familias Numerosas.